# How to get authentication token for Orion context broker

Tags: fiware-orion

There are answers that point to https://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_Quick_Start_for_Programmers . However, proceeding along to the instruction and running "`bash token_script.sh`" I get:

```
Username: <my Fi-Lab log-in address>
Password: <my Fi-Lab password>

Access Token: User credentials not authorized

Organizations:
ID                               Name

Select an organization from the list above (ID):

Token: User token not authorized
```

**Dead end.** Some critical detail may be missing in the Quick_Start_for_Programmers document.
**EDIT:** The problem mysteriously disappeared when retried later. I could do this on a Linux system that was not related to FI-LAB.

Comment: Do you have an account in FIWARE Lab? Are your usernamente/password credentials working when you log in at http://lab.fiware-org? Are you typing the 'Username' with or without the email domain (i.e. if you email were "foo@gmail.com" are you using "foo" or "foo@gmail.com" for username)?

Comment: I have FIWARE lab account and password. (Just successfully logged in.) I replaced my credentials in the quote above by "<my Fi-Lab log-in address>" and "<my Fi-Lab password>" in order not to make them public. After carefully inspecting FIWARE Lab account settings it seems to me that full email address is used there as the username. So, I use full email address with domain as in logging to FIWARE Lab.

Comment: Do you mean that after using your full email as username it worked?

Answer (score 1):

After discussing it (see the comments to the question), the solution is to use the complete username, including email domain, e.g. if the email were "foo@gmail.com" you have to use "foo@gmail.com", not just "foo".

The [Orion Quick Start Guide](https://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_Quick_Start_for_Programmers) has been edited to remark that.